# List of drop in replacements for c++11 functionality

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I'm trying to write a cross platform application for mobile and unfortunately it seems like a lot of potential targets still have poor C++11 support. Is there a list of 'drop-in replacements' for C++11 functionality? Currently I'm planning on using std::shared_ptr, std::unordered_*, and std::thread.

I know that a lot of the new stl features are inspired or pulled from boost libs and sometimes the equivalents can quickly be switched out. For example, boost::unordered_map and boost::unordered_set can be interchanged with the std variants without any changes.

But what about std::shared_ptr and std::thread? If boost doesn't have drop-in replacements for these, are there other libs that do? Is there a list somewhere I can refer to?

Comment: What mobile platforms? More than ios & android? Don't they both support C++11?

Comment: I'm looking at Android, BlackBerry, Tizen, Sailfish and Ubuntu Touch. Actually after a bit more research it seems that only Tizen and Blackberry are outdated. I can probably live with that and just ignore them.

Comment: See if they have `tr` support: many of them where pre-released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you have mentioned has "drop in" replacements from `boost`. In fact, the C++11 thread library is heavily, heavily modelled on boost: so much so, that you can almost do a find and replace `std::` with `boost::` for anything to do with `<thread>`, `<mutex>`, and `<future>` (this is not 100% true, but it's not too far off either).

Similarly for `std::shared_ptr`. You can replace this with `boost::shared_ptr`.

See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html) for the boost thread documentation, and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) for the `shared_ptr` documentation.

Comment: I know that std::thread in particular is not really 1:1 and it seems like I'd have to write a wrapper for threading. Hopefully doing that shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: There are lots of small changes from `boost` to `std`.

Comment: In addition: off the top of my head, C++11 tweaks but is mostly a drop in replacement with: boost atomic, boost chrono, and boost ratio too